# how spring security save RedirectUrl

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am wondering how spring save the information about from which page user came from as after successful authentication Spring security tend to redirect user to same location from where he/she came from.

I know how to get the information out of Spring security by something like

```
protected String getRedirectUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if(session != null) {
        SavedRequest savedRequest = (SavedRequest) session.getAttribute(WebAttributes.SAVED_REQUEST);
        if(savedRequest != null) {
            return savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
        }
    }

    /* return a sane default in case data isn't there */
    return request.getContextPath() + "/";
}
```

But i am not using Spring security in my application and i need to implement same functionality for my Application.
I was wondering where to look in to details as how Spring handle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation for the class `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`. It is responsible to redirect to the same view from where user has come to login page.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.